# How to speed up a python loop?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I'm having trouble finding a solution to speed up a for loop in python. The following code does exactly what i want but is really slow :

```
# CoordEtAngle is an array containing 5 columns
# 1, 2 and 3 column are x y z coordinate of a points
# 4 and 5 values corresponding to those points


points=CoordEtAngle[:,0:3]
NumElem=np.zeros((len(allElem)), dtype=int)
CoordAxelist=[]

for idx,elemcur in enumerate(allElem):
    Coord = np.asarray(map(lambda i: allNodes[i].coordinates, elemcur.connectivity)) # gives me an array containing x,y and z coordinate of a box for each elements
    min_x=np.min(Coord[:,0])
    max_x=np.max(Coord[:,0])
    min_y=np.min(Coord[:,1])
    max_y=np.max(Coord[:,1])
    min_z=np.min(Coord[:,2])
    max_z=np.max(Coord[:,2])
    bound_x = np.logical_and(points[:, 0] > min_x, points[:, 0] < max_x)
    bound_y = np.logical_and(points[:, 1] > min_y, points[:, 1] < max_y)
    bound_z = np.logical_and(points[:, 2] > min_z, points[:, 2] < max_z)
    bb_filter = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(bound_x, bound_y), bound_z)
    NumElem[idx]=np.int(elemcur.label)
    CoordAxelist.append([np.mean(CoordEtAngle[bb_filter,3]),np.mean(CoordEtAngle[bb_filter,4])])
    
CoordAxelist=np.concatenate(CoordAxelist)
```

Thanks in advance for your input. I have a technical issue and i can only use numpy library ...

I did manage to gain some speed using lambda and map in some part of the loop but have no idea how to get even better results

Comment: narrow down your problem, use `line_profiler` to check where is your bottleneck. Done that, create some smaller, **reproducible** example so people here can help you easier and better.

Answer (score -1):

I have several suggestions for you to try:

1. Try to pre allocate `CoordAxelist` before your loop starts
2. Try replacing enumerate with numpy.ndenumerate
3. You can profile your code with cProfile. You can read how to use this profiling tool in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: 1) Pre-allocating `CoordAxelist` is *meaningless*; the cost of shuffling a few pointers around for amortized `list` growth is *nothing* relative to any meaningful amount of work being done here. 2) `enumerate`'s overhead is so low I doubt you'd notice a single cycle saved by replacing it (is `allElem` even a `numpy` array that might benefit from it?). In short: All your specific suggestions are *tiny* micro-optimizations that won't affect the speed of this code in any discernible way.